# setar campo select conforme resultado campo de um campo

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal essa é a minha primeira pergunta, tenho um form e gostaria de preencher o campo select conforme o resultado de um outro campo.
Ex: tenho um campo chamado afastado, ai o user vai la e digita um valor ex: 10, gostaria que o campo select fosse preenchido com o value 0 por exemplo, se o user digitar no campo afastado um valor entre 0 e 10 setar um valor no select se setar entre 11 e 20 setar outro valor no select e assim por diante. podem me ajudar por favor?

```
<form method="POST" action="processa_cad.php">
    <h1>Cadastrar</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nome: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da Empresa ou Filial">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Endereço: </label>
        <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o número e o Logradouro">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Latitude: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lat" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a latitude">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Longitude: </label>
        <input type="text" name="lng" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a mensagem"> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Afastados (%): </label>
        <input type="text" name="afastado" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentual de pessoas afastadas">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Níveis de Risco: </label>
        <select required id="type" name="type" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Selecione nível de risco ...</option>
            <option value="0">Normal</option>
            <option value="1">10% do efetivo baixado</option>
            <option value="2">30% do efetivo baixado</option>
            <option value="3">50% do efetivo baixado</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Estado</label>
        <select name="estado_id" id="estado_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <?php
                            $result_estado = "SELECT * FROM estados est ORDER BY estado_nome ASC";
                            $resultado_estado = mysqli_query($conn, $result_estado);
                            while($row_estado = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_estado)){
                                echo '<option value="'.$row_estado['id'].'">'.$row_estado['estado_nome'].'</option>';

                            }

                        ?>

        </select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
    <div id="btn-cadastrar" class="form-group col-md-5 offset-md-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: essa sua pergunta não tem relação com php, até dá pra fazer por exemplo com o reactPHP mas seria como usar um tiro de canhão para matar uma barata. Sua dúvida tem relação com javascript

Answer (score 0):

As únicas coisa que posso citar é que defina um [`id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) para o elemento quer pretende referenciar pois o atributo `id` especifica o identificador exclusivo do seu elemento e posteriormente pode ser referenciado em javascript por [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) e que o evento ['input'](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input) é disparado quando o valor de exibição de um elemento `<input>`, `<select>`, ou `<textarea>` é alterado.

O resto é código trivial que pode ser explicado nos próprios comentários:

```js
//Somente após o formulário estar carregado.
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  let box = document.getElementById("afastado"); //Obtem a refrencia para <input id="afastado">.

  let select = document.getElementById("type"); //Obtem a refrencia para <select id="type">.

  //Quando houver uma mudança em box
  box.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    val = parseFloat(box.value); //Obtem o valor atual de box e converte para float.

    //Testa sequencialmente algumas condições para ver se são verdadeiras e caso sim altera o valor de select.  
    switch (true) {
      case val <= 10:
        select.value = 0;
        break;
      case val <= 20:
        select.value = 1;
        break;
      case val <= 30:
        select.value = 2;
        break;
      case val <= 40:
        select.value = 3;
        break;
      default: //Se nenhuma condição for atendida
        select.value = "";
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Afastados (%): </label>
  <input type="text" id="afastado" name="afastado" class="form-control" placeholder="Percentual de pessoas afastadas">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Níveis de Risco: </label>
  <select required id="type" name="type" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Selecione nível de risco ...</option>
    <option value="0">Normal</option>
    <option value="1">10% do efetivo baixado</option>
    <option value="2">30% do efetivo baixado</option>
    <option value="3">50% do efetivo baixado</option>
  </select>
</div>
```